# Nashorn and Rhino: Splitting strings by whitespace regexp

Tags: java, javascript, regex, rhino, nashorn

I am parsing Unix shell command outputs in a JavaScript executed by Java's script engine. I often need to split strings by a variable amount of whitespace and have decided to use a regular expression for this.

So far, in Rhino (Java 7 and prior), I could use the following to split strings by whitespace:

```
line.split("\\s+")
```

This no longer works in Nashorn (Java 8 and later), the string is simply not split at all. I have to use the following for Nashorn:

```
line.split(new RegExp("\\s+"))
```

Now - *of course* you might say - this does not work in Rhino. However, I need to maintain compatibility to Java 7 for at least a year to come, so I need a solution that works with both script engines.

I tried this a rather ugly workaround:

```
new java.lang.String(line).split("\\s+")
```

Surprisingly with no luck in Nashorn. Apparently, it somehow forces the creation of its `NativeString` counterpart for strings.

Is there a *nice* solution to split by a variable amount of whitespace, one that works with both script engines? Or do you have to go the "dirty" way - ie determine the script engine from within the script (if that is even possible)?

Comment: Seems to me that it's Rhino that's doing the wrong thing. The spec says that the argument can be a string or a RegExp instance. The implicit conversion to RegExp is therefore clearly wrong.

Comment: Considering my findings that I posted as a comment on Attila's answer, I believe that the problem with Rhino is that there is no implicit conversion from Java strings to JS strings. In the example, I was in fact dealing with a Java string. Converting it using the `String` function works, ie: `String(line).split(new RegExp("\\s+"))`. However, regex literals are less verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a regex literal?

```
line.split(/\\s+/)
```

Should work identically in every JS engine.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know those existed! Apparently, you don't need to escape backslashes, so `/\s+/` does it. One impotant note: in Nashorn (Java 8), you can do it with any string (`java.lang.String`), because there seems to be an implicit conversion to the engine's native string type. When using Rhino (Java 7), you *have* to make sure you are dealing with a JS string, it will *not* work with a Java string. So the solution working in both engines is: `String(line).split(/\s+/)`.